# DynamoDB write cost

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

In DynamoDB does write cost of **updating** an attribute depends only on **attribute size** or total **item size** also?

Say I have a table with partitionid as `userid` and each item has around 70 attributes each of value with 200 bytes. Now I update only 1 attribute of this item. Will write cost be 200 bytes, so **1 Write Capacity Unit** or it will depend on item size irrespective of attributes being updated so will be 70*200=1400 so **2 Write Capacity Units**?

Comment: 70 * 200 should be 14,000 bytes, it should consume 14 WCU not 2.

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting question!

[The Provisioned Throughput documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.html#HowItWorks.ProvisionedThroughput.Writes) talks about **item size**, so I suspect that the whole item is written, thereby causing the consumption of 2 Write Capacity Units.

DynamoDB stores a **blob of data** (as opposed to a traditional SQL database with columns, or a columnar database), so it's likely that the whole blob needs to be rewritten even when an element updates.

If this is a concern, you could **split** a table into multiple tables with the same Partition Key, with less-frequently used data in a different table.

Answer (score 0):

Here are quotes from AWS documentation:

For PutItem:

> PutItem—writes a single item to a table. If an item with the same
>   primary key exists in the table, the operation replaces the item. For
>   calculating provisioned throughput consumption, **the item size that
>   matters is the larger of the two**.

For UpdateItem:

> UpdateItem—modifies a single item in the table. DynamoDB considers the
>   **size of the item as it appears before and after the update**. The
>   provisioned **throughput consumed reflects the larger of these item
>   sizes**. Even if you update just a subset of the item's attributes,
>   UpdateItem will still consume the full amount of provisioned
>   throughput (the larger of the "before" and "after" item sizes).

As you can see in both cases will consider the size of the whole item, not just a single attribute.

One way to fight this is to split attributes int different tables. Then when an attribute is updated you will pay lower cost.

You can split attributes by size (big attributes, like binary data or blobs of text into separate table) or by update frequency. You can even set different RCU/WCU values for different tables to decrease costs even more.

Comment: Yes, but every table must use at least 1 WCU and 1 RCU, In this case, he has to pay for 70 WCU / 70 RCU. That's not really a good solution in my opinion.

Comment: @neiloth: is that accurate with on-demand pricing?